# select from two matrices based on the lowest?

Tags: r

I have these:

```
mat1 <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=5)
mat11 <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=5)

mat2 <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=5)
mat22 <- matrix(runif(100),ncol=5)
```

lets take example :

My output 2 matrices `res1` take value from `mat1` or `mat2` which correspond to lowest between `mat11[1,1]` and `mat22[1,1]` and return this lowest value as `res11`

example :

```
  > mat1[1,1]
          [1] 0.09302976
  > mat11[1,1]
          [1] 0.8775101
  > mat2[1,1]
          [1] 0.6785858
   > mat22[1,1]
          [1] 0.8857934
```

desired output :

```
       res1[1,1]= 0.09302976# was selected because the corresponding mat11 value (0.8775101) was lower than corresponding value to mat22[1,1] 
       res11[1,1]= 0.8775101
```

How to apply this to the whole matrix ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `pmin`

```
pmin(mat1, mat11)
```

Or if it is related to another matrix

```
ifelse(mat11 < mat22, mat1, mat2)
```